# React typescript - How to handle multiple lists in a list

Tags: arrays, reactjs, list, react-typescript

I have a collection of my lists in an array called `allLists`. When I create a new list I add the list to `allLists` array.

I can only add, update, delete elements from the selectedList.

My question is how do keep `allLists` updated with the changes made to `selectedList`.

- How do I update a single list in a collection of lists?
- Should I update using index of the array or by listName?
- Is it best to do this in a useeffect or should i trigger this in a react lifecycle event or is there other ways of doing this?

Codesandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-handle-lists-of-lists-92lez?file=/src/App.tsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export interface ListInterface {
  listName: string;
  list: string[];
}

export default function App() {
  const pokemonList = {
    listName: "Pokemon",
    list: ["Pikachu", "Onix", "Mew"]
  };

  const fruitsList = {
    listName: "Fruits",
    list: ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana"]
  };

  const numbersList = {
    listName: "Numbers",
    list: ["One", "Two", "Three"]
  };

  const [selectedList, setSelectedList] = useState<ListInterface>(numbersList);
  const [allLists, setAllLists] = useState<ListInterface[]>([
    pokemonList,
    fruitsList
  ]);

  const addListToAllLists = () => {
    //Add new list to allList
    if (selectedList?.listName !== "") {
      setAllLists([...allLists, selectedList]);
    }
  };

  const updateAllList = (listName: string) => {
    allLists.forEach((list) => {
      if (list.listName === listName) {
        //set updated list
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedList) {
      //addListToAllLists();
    }
  }, [selectedList]);

  const addMultiElementToList = () => {
    let newList = ["Four", "Five", "Six"];

    setSelectedList({
      ...selectedList,
      list: selectedList.list.concat(newList)
    });
  };

  const addElementToList = () => {
    let newElement = "New Element";

    setSelectedList({
      listName: selectedList.listName,
      list: [...selectedList.list, newElement]
    });
  };

  const changeSelectedList = (listName: string) => {
    console.log("List", listName);
    allLists.forEach((list) => {
      if (list.listName === listName) {
        console.log("Found List", listName);
        setSelectedList(list);
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Selected List [{selectedList.listName}]</h2>
      {selectedList?.list?.map((element) => {
        return <p>{element}</p>;
      })}

      <button onClick={() => addElementToList()}>Add Single Element</button>
      <button onClick={() => addMultiElementToList()}>
        Add Multiple Element
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setSelectedList(numbersList)}>Clear List</button>

      <hr></hr>
      <h2>All Lists</h2>

      <h4>Change Selected List</h4>

      {allLists?.map((list) => {
        return (
          <button onClick={() => changeSelectedList(list.listName)}>
            {list.listName}
          </button>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how do keep `allLists` updated with the changes made to `selectedList`.

You always want a "single source of truth" for data.  `selectedList` should not be its own state.  It is something that is derived from the lists in `allLists` and the name or id of the current list.

```
const [allLists, setAllLists] = useState<ListInterface[]>([
  pokemonList,
  fruitsList,
  numbersList
]);

const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);

const selectedList = allLists[selectedIndex];
```

---

> How do I update a single list in a collection of lists?

You would copy all of the other lists and replace the single list that are modified with a new version.  So you need a copy within a copy.  The Redux guide to [Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-an-item-in-an-array) is a good resource on handling nested updates.

Since you will have multiple similar functions to update the current list, we can remove a lot of repeated code by creating a helper function.

```
const updateCurrentList = (newList: string[]) => {
  setAllLists((lists) =>
    lists.map((current, i) =>
      i === selectedIndex ? { ...current, list: newList } : current
    )
  );
};

const addElementToList = () => {
  let newElement = "New Element";

  updateCurrentList([...selectedList.list, newElement]);
};

const addMultiElementToList = () => {
  let newList = ["Four", "Five", "Six"];

  updateCurrentList(selectedList.list.concat(newList));
};
```

---

> Should I update using index of the array or by `listName`?

I don't feel strongly on this one.  *Accessing* is definitely faster by index as you avoid the need to `find()`.  When you update you always have to do a `map()` to copy the other lists, so there's not much difference.  Technically the `number` comparison of the indexes is faster than the `string` comparison of the names, but this is negligible.

The `listName` would be better if lists are going to be added or removed because the array index might change but the `listName` won't.

---

> Is it best to do this in a `useEffect` or should I trigger this in a react lifecycle event or is there other ways of doing this?

If you follow my advice about keeping data in one place only then there are no dependent updates which need to be done in a `useEffect`.  The primary update of the `allLists` data is triggered by the event.

---

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export interface ListInterface {
  listName: string;
  list: string[];
}

export default function App() {
  const pokemonList = {
    listName: "Pokemon",
    list: ["Pikachu", "Onix", "Mew"]
  };

  const fruitsList = {
    listName: "Fruits",
    list: ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana"]
  };

  const numbersList = {
    listName: "Numbers",
    list: ["One", "Two", "Three"]
  };

  const [allLists, setAllLists] = useState<ListInterface[]>([
    pokemonList,
    fruitsList,
    numbersList
  ]);

  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);

  const selectedList = allLists[selectedIndex];

  // you could make this take a function instead of an array
  // to ensure that it always gets the current value from state
  const updateCurrentList = (newList: string[]) => {
    setAllLists((lists) =>
      lists.map((current, i) =>
        i === selectedIndex ? { ...current, list: newList } : current
      )
    );
  };

  const addElementToList = () => {
    let newElement = "New Element";

    updateCurrentList([...selectedList.list, newElement]);
  };

  const addMultiElementToList = () => {
    let newList = ["Four", "Five", "Six"];

    updateCurrentList(selectedList.list.concat(newList));
  };

  const clearList = () => {
    updateCurrentList([]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Selected List [{selectedList.listName}]</h2>
      {selectedList?.list?.map((element) => {
        return <p>{element}</p>;
      })}

      <button onClick={addElementToList}>Add Single Element</button>
      <button onClick={addMultiElementToList}>Add Multiple Element</button>
      <button onClick={clearList}>Clear List</button>

      <hr></hr>
      <h2>All Lists</h2>

      <h4>Change Selected List</h4>

      {allLists.map((list, i) => {
        return (
          <button onClick={() => setSelectedIndex(i)}>{list.listName}</button>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-handle-lists-of-lists-forked-ycvxd?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Thanks so much. Great explanation! I forgot to ask, how would you handle removing a list from allLists? Here is my example of doing it

`const removeAList = (arrayIndex: number) => {

    const arrayAfterDelete = allLists;

    arrayAfterDelete.splice(arrayIndex, 1);

    setAllLists(arrayAfterDelete);
  }`

Comment: Splice is not a good method to use because it mutates the array. You can only use it if you create a copy of the original array.  Usually I use filter.  You’ll learn pretty quickly which array methods are “safe” and which you need to avoid.

Comment: `const removeList = (arrayIndex: number = selectedIndex) => { setAllLists((lists) => lists.filter((_, i) => i !== arrayIndex)); };`  If we are adding and removing lists then we also need to tweak the `revertList` function to search by name rather than index since index will have changed from the initial to the current.

Answer (score 0):

Think you can get the answer through this.

https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-array-add-update-remove